# Regex to match URL end-of-line or "/" character

Tags: regex

I have a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator), and I'm trying to match it to a regular expression to pull out some groups. The problem I'm having is that the URL can either end *or* continue with a "/" and more URL text. I'd like to match URLs like this:

- http://server/xyz/2008-10-08-4
- http://server/xyz/2008-10-08-4/
- http://server/xyz/2008-10-08-4/123/more

But not match something like this:

- http://server/xyz/2008-10-08-4-1

So, I thought my best bet was something like this:

```
/(.+)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(\d+)[/$]
```

where the character class at the end contained either the "/" or the end-of-line. The character class doesn't seem to be happy with the "$" in there though. How can I best discriminate between these URLs while still pulling back the correct groups?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
/(.+)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(\d+)(/.*)?$
```

**1st Capturing Group `(.+)`**

`.+` matches any character (except for line terminators)

- `+` **Quantifier** — Matches between **one** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed *(greedy)*

**2nd Capturing Group `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`**

`\d{4}` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

- `{4}` **Quantifier** — Matches exactly **4** times

`-` matches the character `-` literally *(case sensitive)*

`\d{2}` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

- `{2}` **Quantifier** — Matches exactly **2** times

`-` matches the character `-` literally *(case sensitive)*

`\d{2}` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

- `{2}` **Quantifier** — Matches exactly **2** times

**`-` matches the character `-` literally *(case sensitive)***

**3rd Capturing Group `(\d+)`**

`\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

- `+` **Quantifier** — Matches between **one** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed *(greedy)*

**4th Capturing Group `(.*)?`**

`?` **Quantifier** — Matches between **zero** and **one** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed *(greedy)*

`.*` matches any character *(except for line terminators)*

- `*` **Quantifier** — Matches between **zero** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed *(greedy)*

**`$` asserts position at the end of the string**

Comment: Why doesn't the last `/` need to be escaped?

Answer (score 137):

To match either / or end of content, use `(/|\z)`

This only applies if you are not using multi-line matching (i.e. you're matching a single URL, not a newline-delimited list of URLs).

To put that with an updated version of what you had:

```
/(\S+?)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(\d+)(/|\z)
```

Note that I've changed the start to be a non-greedy match for non-whitespace ( `\S+?` ) rather than matching anything and everything ( `.*` )

Comment: How do I give you more point ;)  Thanks for this. Just to document (/|\A) would match forward slash or beginning of string.

Comment: Note: JavaScript doesn't support `\Z` and `\z`

Answer (score 69):

You've got a couple regexes now which will do what you want, so that's adequately covered.

What hasn't been mentioned is why your attempt won't work:  Inside a character class, `$` (as well as `^`, `.`, and `/`) has no special meaning, so `[/$]` matches either a literal `/` or a literal `$` rather than terminating the regex (`/`) or matching end-of-line (`$`).

Comment: This is something frequently forgotten and not mentioned eneough in the regex docs.

Comment: Note that ^ can have special meaning in a character class. If it is the first character in the class, it makes it a negative class that will match anything except the other characters. e.g. to match anything except a or b, you could use [^ab]. To include a literal ^, just make sure it isn't first, so to match either a, b or ^ you would use [ab^].

Answer (score 23):

In Ruby and Bash, you can use `$` inside parentheses.

```
/(\S+?)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(\d+)(/|$)
```

(This solution is similar to Pete Boughton's, but preserves the usage of `$`, which means end of line, rather than using `\z`, which means end of string.)

Comment: PHP too from what I can tell. I see no reason why `$` can't be used in parenthesis `()` in any implementation actually. It's the brackets `[]` that make it literal.

Comment: `$` works this way in javascript, whereas `\z` doesn't (Chrome 48, Firefox 43, IE9).

Comment: This is the most straight-forward option. Match slash or end-of-line. It even matches the title of this question!