# Extract until end of line after a special character: Python

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

I need the string after '#' in each line and all lines have the #. I already have a regex matching the line and when I add the comment part to this it doesn't work. I get all the lines after the first comment as one group.

Line format:

```
Line1 blah blah... }}#Comment1 or it could be 
Line1 blah blah...}}# Comment1
```

Either there is a space between the '#' and comment or no space. Right now it matches until the first curly braces.

My code:

```
Linepattern = re.compile(r'\{(\s*(\w+)\s*|(\w+)|(\w+)\s*)\{(.*?)\}', re.DOTALL)
for match in Linepattern.finditer(infile):
    line = matches.group(5)
    #print line
    comment = matches.group(6)
    print comment   # Returns the first comment and then the entire set of lines until end of file
```

I modified my regex to this:

```
Linepattern = re.compile(r'\{(\s*(\w+)\s*|(\w+)|(\w+)\s*)\{(.*?)\}\}(#.*)?', re.DOTALL)
```

I looked at this which is very close to what I am looking for : [Expression up to comment or end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932783/expression-up-to-comment-or-end-of-line)

My output is :

```
Comment1
Line2 # Comment2
Line3 # Comment3 and so on...
```

My lines format:

```
Foo { bar { foo=0; } }# blah1 =1, blah2=1 , blah3 =1, blah#=1
FOO { bar { bar=1;bar=2; } }#comment 2
```

Comment: Does the line format has string literal? If it does, then the solution can be a bit more complex.

Comment: Sorry my question might be lame  but what do you mean by string literal?

Comment: Like, for example, can you declare `{FOO {bar='string'}}`?

Comment: Oh no we cannot. The answer below worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=#).+$
```

Try this.See demo.Set flags `re.M`.

Something like `print re.findall(r"(?<=#).+$",x,re.M)`.Here `x` is your test string.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/3

Comment: @ VKS This regex that you edited a few min ago works perfect. Returns as a list but I need them to be appended after I process each line. Ex I want to print it out like this : Processed Line1 # Comment1 corresponding to line1

Comment: @Doodle you can easily append that to a list .Requires just a loop :)