# Substituting specific string using sed followed by a dot (.)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, substitution

I am doing some substitution in files as follows:

file: abc.txt

```
`include foo.h

int main
{
int foo
foo and bar
barfoobar
}
```

I want to replace 'foo' inside the braces, but I don't want to replace the 'foo' written in the include directive.

I tried using :

```
sed -i "s/\bfoo\b/my_foo/g"
```

Output :

```
`include my_foo.h

int main
{
int my_foo
my_foo and bar
barfoobar
}
```

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/include/b; s/foo/my_&/' foo
include foo.h

int main
{
int my_foo
}
```

This means, if `include` is found, branch jump to end of the command.

Answer (score 2):

To match a string not followed by a . and optionally followed by an end of line

```
sed  -E 's/foo[^.]?$/my_foo/g' test.txt
```

It needs extended regular expressions. The -E on macos or -r on linux (man sed).

There are regex testers such as http://www.regextester.com/ that allow for exploration of regular expressions, or lots of IDE have them built in.

e.g. [Regex to match URL end-of-line or "/" character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175103/regex-to-match-url-end-of-line-or-character)

Comment: This won't work if `foo` is at the end of a line. You need to handle that as well. And you've gotten rid of the `\b` pattern, so it will replace `foo` in the middle of a word.

Comment: OK - answered the "I want to replace the foo. part of the question". I'd add [A-z] after it to get foo.h but that doesn't look like the question to me. The word boundary specification on the start makes sense. It doesn't after the dot. Could be sed -E  's/foo\.([:alpha:]{1})/my_foo.\1/g' test.txt - macos. The answer was wrong though as this gobbles up the . char. Will edit. The square brackets don't do anything.

Comment: What "replace the foo. part of the question"? He said he *doesn't* want to replace that. Read the last line of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i "/^[^`]/ s/\bfoo\b/my_foo/g"
```

What it does is "Only apply the substitution to lines whose first character is not ` (backtick)."

Comment: There's no `#` on his `include` line.

Comment: Can i add a check which could substitute only at places where 'foo' is not followed by a character( or spcl character) ? I added boundaries ( \b) with that intention, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm pretty sure that's because the first time he posted it, the leading `#` make the Markdown parser treat that line as a heading.  I don't think it's too much of an assumption that the real file starts with `#`.

Comment: Perhaps, but it must have been a quick edit because it didn't get put into the history. His sample file looks kind of like C, but it has a bunch of differences.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I don't have a # in include but i do have a backtick (`) .. the other symbol with tilde

Answer (score 0):

I believe this command is what you are looking for:

If you want to replace all lines having `foo` excluding lines with `include`

`sed -i '/foo/ {/include/! s/foo/my_foo/g}' test`

Or
If you want to replace all entries of `foo` excluding entries having `foo.`

`sed -i '/foo/ {/foo./! s/foo/my_foo/g}' test`

As the last line of question and title seems ambiguous, I have answered both situations.

Session output:

```
$ cat test
include foo.h

int main
{
int foo
}
$ 
$ sed -i '/foo/ {/foo./! s/foo/my_foo/g}' test
$ cat test
include foo.h

int main
{
int my_foo
}
```